# TypeError: res.status is not a function in a error handling middleware

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, express

I simply want to add a minimal middleware to handle errors within my express typescript project.
I use errors method from celebration to let it handle celebration/joi errors, and want to add another one to handler other errors.
Here is my code:

```js
app.use(errors()); // celebration error handling
app.use((err: any, req: Request, res: Response) => res.status(300).json(err.message));
```

I order to test it I try to send a GET to an endpoint who doesn't exist, and I keep getting this error: `TypeError: res.status is not a function`

What should I do to be able to use Request like I want ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah yes, but how do I access the error then ?

Comment: Well, **I** just learned something about Express middleware. :-) Thanks! *Really* unfortunate choice they made there, having `err` be an optional *first* parameter. (!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to write [error handling middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.error-handling), you have to provide a function with **four** declared parameters, not just three. So in your case:

```typescript
app.use((err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => res.status(300).json(err.message));
```

Even though you don't use the `next` function in your code, Express can only tell it's an error handler middleware function if it takes four formal parameters. From the documentation linked above:

> Error-handling middleware always takes ***four*** arguments. You must provide four arguments to identify it as an error-handling middleware function. Even if you don’t need to use the `next` object, you must specify it to maintain the signature. Otherwise, the next object will be interpreted as regular middleware and will fail to handle errors.

Express must be looking at the [`length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) of the function in order to know whether it's an error-handling middleware or not.